# Как лучше хранить cookies?

Tags: c#, cookie

Подскажите как лучшего всего хранить куки?

У меня есть БД, и я планирую хранить куки в ней в полях(в текстовом виде), но сомневаюсь насколько это костыльный метод, ведь можно хранить в бд ссылки на файлы куки. И вот вопрос, будет ли сильным костылём хранение куки в текстовом виде в поле БД? Может есть другие предложения их хранения?

Comment: Сериализуйте в какой-нибудь JSON и храните. Я обычно храню JSON просто в файле на диске, в зашифрованном с помощью DPAPI виде. То есть беру `CookieCollection` из контейнера и просто сериализую.

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вам вообще их хранить?

Comment: @aepot спасибо, за совет. Реализую анти-детект браузер